# How to use requirements.txt file in Airflow's PythonVirtualenvOperator?

Tags: airflow

In [Airflow 2.2.3, PythonVirtualenvOperator was updated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17349) to allow templated requirements.txt files in the requirements parameter. However, I am unable to properly utilize that parameter. I am seeking guidance on how to properly utilize a requirements.txt file with Airflow's PythonVirtualenvOperator.

Here's my `/dags` format:

```
dags
├── .airflowignore
├── daily.py
└── modules
    └── monday
        ├── monday.py
        └── requirements.txt
```

In daily.py, I define my daily DAG. The task I'd like to reference requirements.txt for is defined like so:

```
@task.virtualenv(requirements='modules/monday/requirements.txt')
def sync_board_items():
    from modules.monday.monday import sync_board_items
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    sync_board_items(board_id=XXXX, table=XXXX)
```

This seems to fit the implementation described in GitHub, because requirements is a string, not a list, and it complies with the `*.txt` template. However, when the task runs, I quickly receive an error:

```
Executing cmd: /tmp/venvfn63dy3c/bin/pip install m o d u l e s / m o n d a y / r e q u i r e m e n t s . t x t
ERROR: Directory '/' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

This seems to indicate that PythonVirtualenvOperator is treating my requirements param like a list instead of a string. In other words, I am doing something wrong and the PythonVirtualenvOperator is not properly handling my requirements.txt file. What am I missing or how can I leverage a requirements.txt file in Airflow's PythonVirtualenvOperator?

Comment: Not in 2.2.3 but in 2.3.0 which wasn't officially released yet. There is beta version of 2.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature is available only for `Airflow>=2.3.0` it's not available in `2.2.3`

Currently `2.3.0` is under testing. `2.3.0b1` is available via pip.

if you want to use this feature in 2.2.3 you will need to create a custom operator by backporting the code in the [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17349).
Creating a `MyPythonVirtualenvOperator` with the code in the PR and utils should work fine in 2.2.3

Comment: Hi Elad. Can you show an example on how to it ? I'm getting different errors. When passing directly to the PythonVirtualenv class, I get that it can't find the template requirements.txt and when using the @task.virtualenv decoratos, it says that it can find the path, but that I should pass the -r flag. Using Airflow 2.5.1