# How to pass XCom value to PythonVirtualenvOperator as an argument?

Tags: python, airflow

Airflow 2.2.4

I want to create PythonVirtualenvOperator that will pull it's requirements list from another task.

```
with DAG(="crawler") as dag:

    @task(task_id="read_requirements")
    def read_requirements():
        requirements_file_path = "requirements.txt"
        requirements = []
        with open(requirements_file_path, "r") as f:
            requirements = f.readlines()
        return requirements

    def crawler():
        print("hello_world")

    crawler = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id="crawler",
        python_callable=crawler,
        requirements="{{ ti.pull('read_requirements') }}",
    )

    read_requirements() >> crawler
```

Unfortunately, requirements field in PythonVirtualenvOperator does not recognize templates and read this as a plain string. So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999831/how-to-use-requirements-txt-file-in-airflows-pythonvirtualenvoperator

Comment: It doesn't because airflow version is too old. But thanks anyway

Comment: Have you checked the link at the bottom of the answer? it mentions about how you can do with the lower version.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it with wrapping PythonVirtualenvOperator inside decorated function that manages context.

```
with DAG(="crawler") as dag:

    @task(task_id="read_requirements")
    def read_requirements(scraper_path):
        requirements_file_path = f"{scraper_path}/requirements.txt"
        requirements = []
        with open(requirements_file_path, "r") as f:
            requirements = f.readlines()
        return requirements

    scraper_dir = Variable.get("workspace_dir")

    requirements = read_requirements(scraper_dir)
    
    def crawler():
        print("hello_world")

    @task(task_id="crawler_task")
    def crawler_task():
        context = airflow.operators.python.get_current_context()
        ti = context["ti"]
        requirements = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="read_requirements")
        venv_crawler = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
            task_id="venv_crawler",
            requirements=requirements,
            python_callable=crawler,
            dag=dag,
        )
        venv_crawler.execute(context=context)

    requirements >> crawler_task()
```

It feels unnatural and thankfully you can pass .txt file in newer Airflow versions, but it does work this way.